# How do I set a .env file in PyCharm on a Mac?

Tags: macos, environment-variables, pycharm

I'm trying to set up a `.env` file using the Env File plugin for PyCharm, but it's proving more difficult on a Mac compared to on Ubuntu.

The issue is that I can't see hidden files when searching in the plugin on Mac, and unlike on Ubuntu there's no text field where you can just type in the name of the `.env` file. How do I get around this limitation?

Here's the Mac UI with no text field:

[image: Mac UI]

And the Ubuntu UI with the text field:

[image: Ubuntu UI]

Comment: Can you please try the suggestions in this post : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/searching-by-file-name-as-opposed-to-name-and-contents-in-lion

Comment: Thanks. Not really anything relevant there though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The trick to search for hidden files in the Mac UI is to type `command-shift-.` which then shows all the hidden files. You can then select the `.env` file from the results.

Mac UI after using `command-shift-.`:

[image]